# DELL Optiplex 790 Shows only 3rd LED

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios, post, dell-optiplex

My Dell Optiplex 790 Machine is not starting, and only 3rd Diagnostic LED is solid. Sometimes it's starting (After a 100 times restart)
Can anybody tell me what's the real issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Can anybody tell me what's the real issue?

Possible motherboard failure. Get your computer serviced.

> [image]

Source [OptiPlex 790 Owner's Manual](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_optiplex_desktop/optiplex-790_owner%27s%20manual2_en-us.pdf)